# is there JIRA Rest API to get logo/icons of JIRA Projects

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

Is there any API for JIRA Atlassian to fetch project icon/logo.

I'm using /rest/api/latest/project API to fetch projects details from JIRA Atlassian, however there is no Project avatar in this api against each project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you retrieve the details of a project using: [GET /project/{projectIdOrKey}](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/project-getProject) you'll get a result like this:

```
{
    "expand": "description,lead,url,projectKeys",
    "self": "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/project/EX",
    "id": "10000",
    "key": "EX",
    "description": "This project was created as an example for REST.",
    "lead": {
        "self": "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/user?username=fred",
        "name": "fred",
        "avatarUrls": {
            "48x48": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=large&ownerId=fred",
            "24x24": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=small&ownerId=fred",
            "16x16": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&ownerId=fred",
            "32x32": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/useravatar?size=medium&ownerId=fred"
        },
        "displayName": "Fred F. User",
        "active": false
    },

    ...

    "avatarUrls": {
        "48x48": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/projectavatar?size=large&pid=10000",
        "24x24": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/projectavatar?size=small&pid=10000",
        "16x16": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&pid=10000",
        "32x32": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&pid=10000"
    },
    "projectCategory": {
        "self": "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/projectCategory/10000",
        "id": "10000",
        "name": "FIRST",
        "description": "First Project Category"
    }
}
```

The *avatarUrls* part mentions the URLs for the project icon in diferent resolutions.

Note that there is also an *avatarUrls* section under *lead*. This mentions the URLs for the project lead's avatar.

Comment: Thanks,

I got project avatar using below API.

/rest/api/2/project/{ProjectKey}/

Comment: this url will work in browser but in code we need to download image data using GET request and then convert data into Image. we can not assign this image url to imageView as this is not exact image URL.

Comment: if we have projectId (pid), then we can also replace value of pid in below url to get avatar.

http://www.example.com/jira/secure/projectavatar?pid=10000

Comment: when i am downloading image it is not working in mobile, because it is returning content-Type = image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8  instead of image/png.   Any idea how to set avatr as image/png?

Comment: Did you upload your icon as an svg to JIRA? If that's the case, maybe you can try uploading a png?

Comment: I uploaded as .png image.  I will try again. Thanks.

Comment: Strange, then it might even be a bug in the JIRA API.